# Facebook ProfilePictureView did not goes blank after logout

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am trying to make make a app integrated with facebook and I followed the instruction from facebook. However, the "ProfilePictureView" did not return to blank after logout. Is there any ways to "blank" ProfilePictureView or it just don't provide such function?

my code is as following:

```
package com.nick.militarycounter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
private LoginButton loginButton;
private EditText editTextAccount;
private EditText editTextEnterDate;
private Button button1;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private EditText editTextDiscountDays;
private ProfilePictureView facebookProfilePic;
UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    editTextAccount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_account);
    editTextEnterDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enterDate);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    editTextDiscountDays = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_discountDays);
    facebookProfilePic = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_profile_pic);
    textView_userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_loginStatus);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, FBLoginCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton
            .setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                    RegisterActivity.this.mUser = user;
                }
            });

    // Find the user's profile picture custom view
    ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_profile_pic);
    profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

}

ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
GraphUser mUser;
TextView textView_userName;

// The "callback" defined how to handle the login result.
private Session.StatusCallback FBLoginCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // Failed
        if ((exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this).setTitle("取消")
                    .setMessage("登入失敗!").setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                    .show();
            textView_userName.setText("登入失敗");

        } // Successed
        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            textView_userName.setText("請按登入鍵登入");
            // should reset image of profilePictureView HERE!
        } else {
            textView_userName.setText("登入中...");
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }

    }
};

/**
 * Set the user name and image
 * 
 * @param session
 */
private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
    // Make an API call to get user data and define a
    // new callback to handle the response.
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            mUser = user;
                            facebookProfilePic.setProfileId(user.getId());
                            textView_userName.setText(user.getName());
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        // Handle errors, will do so later.

                    }
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, " onResume");

    // 這個是用來檢查是不是由facebook中notification連結而來
    // 同時讀取相關的資訊
    // checkReceivedRequest();

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton
            .setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                    RegisterActivity.this.mUser = user;
                }
            });

    // Find the user's profile picture custom view
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_profile_pic);
    profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Please Try :

```
 // Remaining above code :
    else if (state.isClosed()) {
        textView_userName.setText("請按登入鍵登入");
        // should reset image of profilePictureView HERE!
        profilePictureView.setImageBitmap(null);

    } else {
        textView_userName.setText("登入中...");
        makeMeRequest(session);
    }

}
```

OR USE THE BELOW METHOD:

```
public final void setDefaultProfilePicture(Bitmap inputBitmap)
```

The ProfilePictureView will display the provided image while the specified profile is being loaded, or if the specified profile is not available.
Parameters
inputBitmap The bitmap to render until the actual profile is loaded.

Comment: setDefaultProfilePicture(null) do not works! but i think setDefaultProfilePicture(Bitmap inputBitmap) will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I trace profilePictureView and make setBlankProfilePicture() a public function!

setBlankProfilePicture() set the image back to default image.

However, profilePictureView do not refresh once log in again...

Activity must be restarted to load image into profilePictureView.

Answer (score 1):

set the ProfileId to null to reset the profile picture to default view after logging out.

Example:

profilePicture.setProfileId(null);